# Joined columns not visible in final result using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join

I am a newbie in R, I have the following code for doing some aggregations on the movie lens dataset in R using dplyr

```
joined_data <- inner_join(ratings_data,movie_data,by="movie_id",copy=TRUE)  
data <- joined_data %>% group_by(movie_id) %>% arrange(movie_id) 
data1 <- data %>% select(movie_id,movie_title,rating) %>% summarize(count_ratings=n())
```

The data tbl has all the columns I want(movie_id,movie_title,rating,...) I'm trying to select only 3 columns and summarize them, but the data1 tbl does not have the movie_title which was from the second table(movie_data). Any reason why this is happening? How do I get the columns I want in data1?

**names(data)**

```
 [1] "user_id"            "movie_id"           "rating"             "timestamp"          "movie_title"       
 [6] "release_date"       "video_release.date" "IMDb_URL"           "unknown"            "Action"            
 [11] "Adventure"          "Animation"          "Childrens"          "Comedy"             "Crime"             
 [16] "Documentary"        "Drama"              "Fantasy"            "Film_Noir"          "Horror"            
 [21] "Musical"            "Mystery"            "Romance"            "Sci_Fi"             "Thriller"          
 [26] "War"                "Western"
```

But when I do this :

```
data1 <- data %>% select(movie_id,movie_title,user_id,rating) %>% summarize(count_users=n(),count_ratings=n())
```

**names(data1)**

```
 [1] "movie_id"      "count_users"   "count_ratings"
```

Comment: We need to see some data to understand where you lose that column. Also, are you sure you really need `copy=TRUE` in the first line of code? What do you achieve with `group_by(movie_id) %>% arrange(movie_id)`? Why you don't just arrange?

Comment: In case if you have movie_title in both initial tables (ratings_data and movie_data) with joining R adds ending to the name movie_title.x, movie_title.y. this could be possible reason, why you cannot find movie_title without ending

Comment: both the tables do not have "movie_title" . The join is done based on "movie_id"

Comment: @AntoniosK , I need the group by to summarize ratings later on , I am losing the columns when I try to summarize and write the result to another dataframe.

Comment: I think that `group_by(movie_id)` in your second line is responsible for that. Can you use `group_by(movie_id, movie_title)` and check again?

Comment: @AntoniosK , that was the reason, thanks a lot !

Comment: Great! The moment you call `summarise` it will look at what variables you `group_by` and will ignore all other variables no matter if you `select` them. A simple example is this `library(dplyr);

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  select(cyl, am, disp) %>%
  summarise(N = n())`.

Comment: I also think you have some unnecessary parts in your code. Looks like you can pipe everything like this `inner_join(ratings_data,movie_data,by="movie_id") %>% 
  group_by(movie_id, movie_title) %>% 
  summarize(count_ratings=n())`

Comment: @AntoniosK, thank you , I usually try to pipe the code , but this left me confused !! Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

`group_by(movie_id)` in your second line is responsible for that. Can you use:

```
group_by(movie_id, movie_title)
```

and check again - this worked as suggested by @AntoniosK